# Не удается запарсить JSON в tableview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

Не могу правильно декодировать JSON.

Вот сам JSON (прошу прощения, что фото):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Декодинг:

```
  struct News_data: Decodable {
    let data: [Article_Data]

     enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case data = "data"

    }
}

struct Article_Data: Decodable {
    let title: String
    let image: String
    let cat: Category

     enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case title = "title"
        case image = "image"
        case cat = "cat"
    }

}

struct Category: Decodable {
    let type: String
     enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case type = "title"
    }
}
```

Функция:

```
var arrData = [Article_Data]()

func getCoinData() {
    let jsonURL = "https://abctv.kz/ru/api/v1/getMainList"
    guard let url = URL(string: jsonURL) else { return }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { [unowned self] (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
            let data_new = try decoder.decode(News_data.self, from: data)
          }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.arrData = data_new.data
                self.tableview.reloadData()
            }

        } catch {
            print("Error is : \n\(error)")
        }
        }.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зачем пишете вопрос который уже задавали? Лучше исправляйте существующий вопрос.

Вы не прописали инициализаторы для `Decodable`.
А так-же параметр `cat` является опциональной строкой.

Финальное решение должно выглядеть вот так.

```
struct News_data: Decodable {
  let data: [Article_Data]

  enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
    case data = "data"
  }
  init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    let data = try container.decode([Article_Data].self, forKey: CodingKeys.data)
    self.data = data
  }
}

struct Article_Data: Decodable {
  let title: String
  let image: String
  let cat: String?

  enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
    case title = "title"
    case image = "image"
    case cat = "cat"
  }

  init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    let title = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: CodingKeys.title)
    let image = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: CodingKeys.image)
    let cat = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: CodingKeys.cat)

    self.title = title
    self.image = image
    self.cat = cat
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное