# Swift-парсинг JSON через Instagram ?__a=1

Tags: json, swift, парсер, instagram

Есть интересная ссылка инстаграмма: https://instagram.com/instagram/?__a=1, по которой в ответ я получаю json, хочу реализовать парсинг по нужным мне критериям.

Создал структуру и декодер, но при попытке получить что-либо высвечивает **ошибку**, что это не JSON:

> dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [],
>   debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.",
>   underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840
>   "No value." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value.})))

**Код программы:**

```
    struct Page: Decodable {
    let graphql: [User]

    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case graphql = "graphql"
    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let graphql = try container.decode([User].self, forKey: CodingKeys.graphql)
        self.graphql = graphql
    }
}

struct User: Decodable {
    let user: [Sets]

    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case user = "user"
    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let user = try container.decode([Sets].self, forKey: CodingKeys.user)
        self.user = user
    }
}

struct Sets: Decodable {
    let profile_pic: String
    let posts: [CountPosts]

    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case profile_pic = "profile_pic_url"
        case posts = "edge_owner_to_timeline_media"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let profile_pic = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: CodingKeys.profile_pic)
        let posts = try container.decode([CountPosts].self, forKey: CodingKeys.posts)

        self.profile_pic = profile_pic
        self.posts = posts
    }
}

struct CountPosts: Decodable {
    let count: Int

    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case count = "count"
    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let count = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: CodingKeys.count)
        self.count = count
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let urlStr = "https://www.instagram.com/instagram/?__a=1"
        guard let url = URL(string: urlStr) else { return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else {return}
            guard error == nil else {return}

            do {
                let page = try JSONDecoder().decode(Page.self, from: data)
                print(page)
            }catch let error{
                print(error)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне правильно решить эту ошибку?

Comment: Сегодня уже обсуждали эту проблему.  Вы не создаете инициализаторы. Посмотрите это решение https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/917948/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-json-%D0%B2-tableview . Если не разберетесь, распишу решение.

Comment: @ВикторМишустин Спасибо большое)

Comment: @ВикторМишустин попробовал переделать как в этом примере, но ошибка осталась та же(

Comment: @Jefoce СountVideo там count типа Int а не String

Comment: @Horoko все равно ошибка "The given data was not valid JSON"

Comment: З.Ы Иниты эти бесползены, т.к проперти ваших структур совпадают с JSON. Инит нужно писать для переопределения данных при декодинге.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эта ссылка недоступна. https://www.instagram.com/instagram/?__a=1
Вы пытаетесь осуществить запрос без указания дополнительных полей индентифицирующих ваш аккаунт в Instagram. 
[Instagram API](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/)

З.Ы попробуйте в режиме инкогнито перейти на ссылку (она не откроется)

Comment: Понял, спасибо)